# Connect to an ASP.NET API using PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, json, api

Here's my code to convert the `Array` into `json`

```
$specific = [];

  $specific[] = ["message" => $row["traditionalmessage"],
              "mobile" => $row["telMobile"]];
}
 echo json_encode($specific,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Here's my result

```
[{"message":"hi","mobile":"96709394"},{"message":"hello","mobile":"96709394"}]
```

Now,I have to connect to an ASP.Net API using PHP.
As the API has login set up
, I am required to send the header with 2 key

```
[{"key":"Token","value":"2:6oWlvd2rYwBMmsVOMBrtDDJMofgIlX"}]
[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"}]
```

Any ideas on connecting to the ASP.NET API?
Thanks